# Run time error in scala : NoSuchMethodError

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to use Spark MLlib algorithm's in Scala language in eclipse. There are no problems during compilation and while running there is an error saying "NoSuchMethodError".

Here is my code #Copied

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib._


object LinearRegression {
   def truncate(k: Array[String], n: Int): List[String] = {
        var trunced = k.take(n - 1) ++ k.drop(n)
       // println(trunced.length)
       return trunced.toList
       }
    }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("linear     regression").setMaster("local"))

//Loading Data
    val data = sc.textFile("D://Innominds//DataSets//Regression//Regression Dataset.csv")
    println("Total no of instances :" + data.count())

//Split the data into training and testing
    val split = data.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2))
    val train = split(0).cache()
    println("Training instances :" + train.count())
    val test = split(1).cache()
    println("Testing instances :" + test.count())
    //Mapping the data
    val trainingRDD = train.map {
      line =>
        val parts = line.split(',')
        //println(parts.length)
        LabeledPoint(parts(5).toDouble, Vectors.dense(truncate(parts,    5).map(x => x.toDouble).toArray))
    }
    val testingRDD = test.map {
      line =>
    val parts = line.split(',')
    LabeledPoint(parts(5).toDouble, Vectors.dense(truncate(parts, 5).map(x => x.toDouble).toArray))
}

val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(trainingRDD, 20)

val predict = testingRDD.map { x =>
  val score = model.predict(x.features)
  (score, x.label)
}

val loss = predict.map {
  case (p, l) =>
    val err = p - l
    err * err
}.reduce(_ + _)

val rmse = math.sqrt(loss / test.count())

println("Test RMSE = " + rmse)

sc.stop()
```

}

The error arises while developing model i.e.,

```
Var model = LInearRegressionWithSGD(trainingRDD,20).
```

The print statements before this line are printing the values on console perfectly.

Dependencies in pom.Xml are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Error in eclipse:

```
15/03/19 15:11:32 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 6 from broadcast at     GradientDescent.scala:185
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate$default$4(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
        at          org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1.a pply$mcVI$sp(GradientDescent.scala:189)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
        at     org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$.runMiniBatchSGD(GradientDes cent.scala:184)
        at     org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent.optimize(GradientDescent.sca la:107)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLine arAlgorithm.scala:263)
        at 
    org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLine arAlgorithm.scala:190)
        at     org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD$.train(LinearRegressio n.scala:150)
        at     org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD$.train(LinearRegressio n.scala:184)
        at Algorithms.LinearRegression$.main(LinearRegression.scala:46)
        at Algorithms.LinearRegression.main(LinearRegression.scala)
```

Comment: please add the complete stacktrace of NoSuchMethodError to your question

Comment: You have a version mismatch between spark core and spark mlib.

Comment: mllib v1.3.0  vs spark-core v1.2.1  - pls align both

Answer (score 1):

You're using `spark-core` 1.2.1 and `spark-mllib` 1.3.0. Make sure you use the same version for both dependencies.